# Consecutive visited days not updating through mobile access

Tags: support

I was logging into the Stack Overflow site through mobile on Sundays. But consecutive visited day is not updating. How will it work?

Comment: Only logging in? Did you actually do anything after logging in? Because logging in alone does not count as activity which counts towards those badges.

Comment: Yes :)  what activities should be there to update count?

Comment: @SanthoshNayak That is a secrete.  If you review a couple things that should count.